# Converting Emberjs Model to JSON with Local Storage Adapter

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

In my Application i want to convert my models to json and then send this json to server.for adapter i use [LSA](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter).

Fore example i have model like this :

```
App.AxisModel = DS.Model.extend({
 uniqueName: DS.attr('string'),
 name: DS.attr('string'),
 hierarchyUniqueName: DS.attr('string'),
 type: DS.attr('string'), //row,column,filter
 isMeasure: DS.attr('boolean'),
 isActive: DS.attr('boolean'), //is added to one of type 
 orderId: DS.attr('number'),
 isAll:DS.attr('boolean'),
 sort:DS.attr('string'),
});
```

And a Sample for json :

```
{
"OlapApp.AxisModel": {
    "records": {
        "htlbv": {
            "id": "htlbv",
            "uniqueName": "[Customers].[(All)]",
            "name": "(All)",
            "hierarchyUniqueName": "[Customers]",
            "type": "column",
            "isMeasure": false,
            "isActive": true,
            "orderId": 0,
            "isAll": true,
            "sort": "none"
        },
        "t58i9": {
            "id": "t58i9",
            "uniqueName": "[Sellers].[(All)]",
            "name": "(All)",
            "hierarchyUniqueName": "[Sellers]",
            "type": "row",
            "isMeasure": false,
            "isActive": true,
            "orderId": 0,
            "isAll": true,
            "sort": "none"
        },
        "2t9lc": {
            "id": "2t9lc",
            "uniqueName": "[Cube1].[Cube1-1]",
            "name": "Cube1-1",
            "hierarchyUniqueName": "[Database].[Cube1]",
            "type": "filter",
            "isMeasure": true,
            "isActive": true,
            "orderId": 0,
            "isAll": false,
            "sort": "none"
         }
      }
 }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for that format of the JSON? Is that what the server expects? It looks to me like you're sharing the JSON in the LocalStorage, the one formatted and added by the Local Storage Adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options

1. You could look at using the RESTAdapter instead of the LocalStorage one if you want to communicate with the server. It's quite flexible and you could override model specific serializers (e.g.  App.Model will be serialized by App.ModelSerializer) or override some defaults.
2. If you have a hybrid of REST+LocalStorage and you want to synchronize changes manually, you could format it using JSON.parse and JSON.stringify and communicate with the server using jQuery and synching the changes locally. You can look at the following answer for an example of [how to do this for create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635171/how-to-add-record-to-the-store-after-it-is-saved/19648856#19648856).