# How to add record to the Store after it is saved

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Using the following syntax to create a record, adds it to the Store immidiatly:

```
store.createRecord('post', {title: "Rails is omakase"});
```

What is the way to successfully store the record on the server and only then add it to the Store?

I would expect store.createRecord to return a promise. Very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

One could argue that having the "potential" records in your local store isn't the problem, but having them show up in a list that is intended for showing saved records.

So, I made a component to use when I only want to show saved records:

**app/components/each-saved.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const EachSavedComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

  tagName: '',

  savedRecords: Ember.computed.filterBy('records', 'isNew', false)

});

EachSavedComponent.reopenClass({
  positionalParams: ['records']
});

export default EachSavedComponent;
```

**app/templates/components/each-saved.hbs**

```
{{#each savedRecords as |record|}}
  {{yield record}}
{{/each}}
```

**Usage**

```
<div class="CARD">
  <table class="LIST">
    {{#each-saved model.users as |user|}}
      <tr>
        <td class="LIST-cell">{{user.name}}</td>
        <td class="LIST-cell--right"><a href="" class="BUTTON">Remove</a></td>
      </tr>
    {{/each-saved}}
  </table>
</div>
```

I don't need it everywhere and there are a few cases where I do want unsaved records to show up in a list.

Answer (score 0):

For what you mentioned I guess you're calling the server directly (instead of through the REST Adapter). If that is the case, you can:

```
var store = store;
$.ajax(url, {type: 'POST', success: function (savedRecord) {
  var pushedRecord = store.push(App.MyModel, savedRecord);
  pushedRecord.save();
});
```

Comment: Isn't the whole point of ember-data to abstract all that. Why call save on the record if you already saved it manually?

Comment: createRecord would be used if there's something new that doesn't exist in the server, but it's only added to the store. No need to return a promise since all of this is done synchronously in memory in the store. Push will add an existing record to the store. In both cases, save will actually go to the adapter and persist the in memory changes. I'm assuming you're not using the REST Adapter, since you said you want to first save it to the server and then add it to the store. Can you expand more on your use case to provide a better answer?

Comment: Here it is http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/why-does-store-createrecord-create-a-record-immediately/3161/2

Comment: That's a bit clearer there. I understand the intention behind this and it has nothing to do with what I thought of the adapter. I think what you want is `buildRecord` instead of `createRecord`. The latter sets that as loaded, which means is on the store, so it will appear on lists that might be bound to that collection. Hope this helps.